# Concatenate variable in Apex in salesforce?

Tags: apex

In salesforce batch class I am trying to do something like below, but its giving me error

```
global class PurgerefundcasesBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    private static final String refund = 'refund';

    String query = String query = 'SELECT id, SubStatus__c FROM Case ' + 
                        'WHERE SubStatus__c ='+ refund +' AND createdDate < LAST_N_DAYS:10';

    global PurgerefundcasesBatch() {

    }
    .......
    .........
}
```

Getting the below error..

```
Timestamp: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 21:59:17
   Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: classes/PurgeDraftcasesBatch.cls: Missing ';' at 'query' (Line: 12, Column: 24)
classes/PurgeDraftcasesBatch.cls: Unexpected token '='. (Line: 12, Column: 30)
classes/PurgeDraftcasesBatch.cls: Unexpected token '='. (Line: 12, Column: 30)
classes/PurgeDraftcasesBatch.cls: Unexpected token '+'. (Line: 13, Column: 41)
classes/PurgeDraftcasesBatch.cls: Unexpected token '+'. (Line: 13, Column: 41)
classes/PurgeDraftcasesBatch.cls: Variable does not exist: String (Line: 12, Column: 17)
classes/PurgeDraftcasesBatch.cls: Invalid loop variable type expected SObject was Case (Line: 26, Column: 4)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this like below. Please refer to [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) for dynamic query considerations

```
private static final String refund = 'refund';

String query = 'SELECT id, SubStatus__c FROM Case ' + 
                'WHERE SubStatus__c = :refund AND createdDate < LAST_N_DAYS:10';
```

Answer (score 0):

The major issiue is that you set your query variable in a wrong way. You can't define it like:

```
String query = String query =

String query = 'SELECT id, ELC_SubStatus__c FROM Case WHERE SubStatus__c ='+ refund +' AND createdDate < LAST_N_DAYS:10';
```